# enabling viewstate in webparts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-config, viewstate

I am using `viewstate` in my webparts

```
ViewState["CurrentPageNo"] = 22;
```

But this is not working on my production environment as `enableview` state is false in `web.config`. How can we enable it on pagelevel without modifying `web.config`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable it in the Master page and see if it works. something like this

```
<@Page EnableViewState="true" />
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f3629e65-d125-4c4d-9c80-c9e18b1088a1/viewstate-in-master-page-is-missing?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

But it is really recomendid to do this via web.config.